# goBack always taking to home/first screen in react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am working on an app but goback button is not taking me to the back screen.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import one from './components/test/one';
import two from './components/test/two';
import three from './components/test/three';

import { DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const AppNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
    one: {
      screen: one,
    },
    two: {
      screen: two,
    },
    three: {
      screen: three,
    },
  }
);

export default () =>
      <AppNavigator />;
```

components/test/one.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';

export default class one extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    drawerLabel: 'one',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('two')}
        title="Go to Two"
      />
    );
  }
}
```

components/test/two.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';

export default class two extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    drawerLabel: 'two',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('three')}
        title="Go to 3"
      />
    );
  }
}
```

components/test/three.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';

export default class three extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    drawerLabel: 'three',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
        title="Go back to 2"
      />
    );
  }
}
```

click on "Go to two" => "Go to 3" => "Go back to 2".
on screen 3, clicking on the "Go back to 2" is always taking me to one.js.

It is not even working if I combine them in one single file.

Answer (score 8):

You are either using the wrong `Navigator` comp or your requirements are not clear. Basically, You would like to use the `StackNavigator` for your desired behavior.

The catch is, `DrawerNavigator` is used to build up a drawer menu. If you swipe from the left you'll see your navigator drawer containing all of your screens, as you can see in the image below.

[image]

If you add a button on your screen like below, you'll see your menu open.

```
<Button title="MENU" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')} />
```

The conclusion is, whenever we use `DrawerNavigator` we always go back to initial route, which is whatever we defined as the first item or using the `initialRouteName` key of the second param of the `DrawerNavigator`.

It's only the `StackNavigator` that supports this stacking order you would like to achieve, as the name suggests itself.

What you can do is to wrap a new `StackNavigator` inside one of the screens of the `DrawerNavigator`. For example:

```
const AppNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
    drawer1: {
        screen: drawer1,
    }
});

const drawer1 = StackNavigator({
    one: { screen: one },
    two: { screen: two },
    three: { screen: three },
});
```

Comment: This answer absolutely saved my day.:) Thanks.

Comment: How to pass params to screen 'one' from drawerNavigator?

Comment: Try changing drawer1 variable name and it's usage.